# how can I rescale an integer array of data to an integer one?

Tags: data-transformation

I have an array of data.for example {25,26,11}.I want to rescale them to an array in which the summation of the 3 data is a definite value (for example 10).how can i do that?!

Comment: Your comment to the (accepted) answer indicates you are expecting something that is mathematically impossible. Your example sums to 62, so rescaling its values to sum to 10 necessarily produces non-integral results.  I have concluded that vital information must be missing from the question.

Comment: dear whuber the point is I'm working on a statistical issue and some little errors are not important to me.I have a population of something and it will grow in a period of time.I want to iterate the process every time with the same population as the first time and just their position would differ.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple thing to do but I will walk you through the derivation. Your goal is to take the sum of a series of numbers $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$ and set that sum to a value, which is just scaling it $a\cdot \sum_{i=1}^Nx_i = k$. So to get your solution all you need to do is divide your target value ($k$ in this case) by your sum $a = \frac{k}{\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i}$ to get your scaling factor.

Comment: thanx for your useful answer but the main problem is that i want the second array to be integers.consequently sometimes the summation would not be what i want.